# 2 external monitors 1 laptop resolution cannot set to native resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

I have two external monitors connected to my laptop via a USB 3.0 to HDMI splitter. I intend to have the laptop lid closed and only use the external monitors. This is working. The problem is one of the monitors is only giving me resolution options from the laptop.

I have tried disabling the laptop display with the lid open but this disables my 3rd monitor also, the one which is inherently getting the laptops resolutions.

When I use all 3 monitors I am able to get both externals to use their native resolutions when I am using duplicate from laptop to monitors. However when I switch it to extend the third monitor only use the laptops resolutions.

How do I tell the 3rd monitor to use it's own driver or what can I do?